# Pros and cons of Open Collective vs. GitHub Sponsors?

Tags: finance, donations

I want to sponsor an open source project on behalf of our *company* – that is an important detail. The project (Yarn) has both [Open Collective](https://opencollective.com/yarnpkg) and [GitHub sponsors](https://github.com/sponsors/yarnpkg), two questions I basically have:

1. Is either of them better for *them*? Let's say we contribute $100/mo., will they get the same amount through both platforms or are there any deductions / fees?
2. Is either of them better for *us*? I've only ever sponsored as an individual so I'm not sure if our accountant will want to see some sorts of documents (an equivalent of an invoice I guess) or similar.

Comment: For (1), it seems your best bet by far would be to ask the project you'll be contributing to. They may have reasons for preferring one or the other you'd never be able to guess at.

Answer (score 2):

I found this articles which gives some answers: Open Collective's response to the introduction of GitHub Sponsors https://medium.com/open-collective/on-github-sponsors-5450b63caf7d :

> How is Open Collective different?
>
> 1. Open Source
> 2. Fully Transparent
> 3. Built for Projects
> 4. Fiscal Sponsorship
>
> Additionally:
> GitHub is Microsoft, which has its own metrics in mind, and it will be difficult for them to be independent, regardless of the good faith of the folks involved.

Not that it's also possible to link GitHub Sponsors to Open Collective to centralize things: https://docs.oscollective.org/campagins-programs-and-partnerships/github-sponsors https://opencollective.com/github-sponsors